# Grep specific part of text

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text like this:

```
ora.sas.aa.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1                                         
ora.sas.bb.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas2                                         
ora.sas.cc.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas2                                         
ora.sas.dd.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1                                         
ora.sas.ee.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1                                         
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas2
```

What i want is to grep specific part of this `.svc` and online status like:

> ```
> example.txt |grep aa
> ```

```
  ora.sas.aa.svc
          1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1
```

or

> ```
> example.txt |grep ee
> ```

```
 ora.sas.ee.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1                                         
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas2
```

row number of "online" may change, so i can't grep with `grep -A2` or `grep -A3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk instead:

```
awk -v s='ee' 'NF==1 && $0 ~ s{p=1} NF==1 && !($0 ~ s){p=0} p' file
ora.sas.ee.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas2

awk -v s='aa' 'NF==1 && $0 ~ s{p=1} NF==1 && !($0 ~ s){p=0} p' file
ora.sas.aa.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can do it with grep, but you can definitely do it with awk.

```
<example.txt awk 'NF==1 { got_match = ($0 ~ /PATTERN/)} got_match {print}'
```

Replace PATTERN with "ee" or "aa" and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ func() {
> sed -n "/$1/{:a;p;n;/^[[:space:]]/ba}" "$2"
> }
$ func aa example.txt
ora.sas.aa.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1
$ func ee example.txt
ora.sas.ee.svc
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas1
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       sas2
```